# How do i get this IF statement to work in MYSQL (it's in a stored procedure)?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, procedure

I can't find an example anywhere that doesn't give me syntax errors

My code is

```
BEGIN
UPDATE Room_Descriptions
IF(STRCMP(Bed_Type,'King')) THEN SET Max_People = Number_Beds * 3
END
```

Basically it's supposed to go through the table and look at the column "Bed_Type", if it finds the word "King" it'll multiply that row's Number_Beds by 3 and set that in the column Max_People

I was hoping to eventually get some if elses going on but I'll settle for just one if that works.

Comment: STRCMP? you are very creative.

Comment: I don't think `STRCMP()` is what you want. It will be false if `Bed_Type` exactly equals 'King' and true otherwise. You probably just want `Bed_Type = 'King'`. Or, if you're looking for the word 'King' somewhere within a larger piece of text, `Bed_Type LIKE '%King%'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE Room_Descriptions SET Max_People = Number_Beds*3 WHERE STRCMP(Bed_Type,'King')
```

All it takes is a conditional UPDATE.

Comment: No I need an if statement for the assignment, and nothing I've tried is working

Comment: The query I gave you does exactly what you're trying to do: it sets the max people to triple the number of beds when the bed type is King.

Comment: No I have an assignment that specifically calls for an if statement.

Comment: @RobertZ It's a strange thing to do, but perhaps you could `UPDATE Room_Descriptions SET Max_People = IF(STRCMP(Bed_Type,'King'), Number_Beds*3, Number_Beds);` to incorporate an `IF()`? _(@Kolink's suggestion is the "right" way to do this, so forcing the use of `IF()` seems like an exercise in futility, probably merely aimed at practicing its usage and thinking outside the box.)_

Comment: No wait it seems the last two need to be reversed I think it should be UPDATE Room_Descriptions SET Max_People = IF(STRCMP(Bed_Type,'King'), Max_People, Number_Beds*3);

Comment: @RobertZ Oh yes, you're right. It should be `Number_Beds*3`, and `Max_People` instead of `Number_Beds` a second time. My mistake. But see my comment on the question itself above; I think your condition is wrong.